# Why isn't my relativelayout filling the screen? - android

Tags: android

I am struggling to figure out why my relativelayout screen is not filling the entire screen.  I have tried a number of things, but the horizontal space of the screen never appears filled.  What am i doing wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
    android:background="@color/splashScreenBackgroundColor"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="MyAppName"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice fill_parent is the same as match_parent.  They renamed it in v8, but both names work the same way (they have the same value).

Comment: I see that it is filling the screen in it's entirety vertically.  And almost filling the screen horizontally.  On the horizontal side, there is about 8% blank space on either side of the screen

Comment: working on getting the snapshot

Comment: To which view are you adding this RelativeLayout? It may have left and right padding.

Comment: I am not adding this to a view, but it does appear before my main activity.  My main activity screen has no padding and no margin values in the file at this time.  This screen is like the introduction screen that appears for 3 seconds before showing the apps main screen

Answer (score 1):

The old name is deprecated, change the values to this..

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Adding singletop will replace the last instance of your activity so if that solved your problem maybe you are instantiating your activity more than once somewhere, and that is why didnt worked before.

Comment: fill_parent and match_parent are the same thing.  They renamed it for some unknown reason, but they act equivalently.

Comment: But `fill_parent` should be replaced with `match_parent` to avoid deprecation issues. Anyway, not the problem but when you post an answer like this you should indicate *where* these values should be changed.

Comment: changed to match_parent permanently.  Again, this did not change the issue, but its good to be using terms that will not be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  I added
"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
"
to the relativelayout and it solved the problem!

Comment: So the problem is actually not in the part you posted, but in its relationship to something else you didn't?

Comment: That means that the last instance of your activity is overriden when making a new intent for that activity, maybe your are initializing your activity more than once

Comment: Thanks!  I continued to inspect my app and noticed that I was calling a second version of the app in a class call, so I changed it to getContext() and then removed the previous entry and it solved the issue.  thanks